# How to excape % in string like "%SOme;string" in C# CodedUI

Tags: c#, wpf, string, escaping

i write a CodedUI test in C# for a wpf application. I need to write a value (string like **"%Some;"string?""**) to the TextBox. I created  a string `var newMaterialName = "\"%Some;\"string?\"\"";` and wrote it to the TextBox. As a result this string was added like **"ome;"string?""** - so "%S" disappeared. I really must write to the TextBox exact string with % sign in it. (%%, ,\%, and \x25 - do not work) If u ever met this problem, give a hint. Thanx.

Comment: have you tried with **@**"%S"?

Comment: yes, but %S disappears

Answer (score 1):

Try using it like this as a verbatim string:

```
 var newMaterialName = @"""%Some;string?""";
```

Comment: thanks for your answere but it returns "me;string?" not " "%Some;"string?"" "

Comment: what version of c# are you using?

Comment: I'm using v4.0.3.0319